# StreamPlot fails on complex values

Tags: plotting

I've got some functions to `StreamPlot` that take on complex values in some of the domain.  According to "Details and Options" in the manual page:

> StreamPlot does not show streamlines at any positions for which the vi etc. do not evaluate to real numbers.

Fair enough. The following minimal example works as expected:

```
StreamPlot[{Sqrt[1 - x], Sqrt[1 - y]}, {x, 0, 1.5}, {y, 0, 1.5}]
```

[image]

However, this similar call fails to evaluate:

```
StreamPlot[{Sqrt[1 - x], Sqrt[1 - y]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

What gives?  Is this a bug?  What determines success vs. failure?  Are there any general work-arounds?

```
$Version
(* 13.2.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (November 18, 2022) *)
```

Comment: As a workaround, `StreamPlot[{ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[1 - x], x <= 1], ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[1 - y], y <= 1]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]`

Comment: I would call this a bug

Comment: I've seen this behavior before. If you do `Trace@StreamPlot[{Sqrt[1 - x], Sqrt[1 - y]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]` you'll see lots of `Failed` messages showing also. I could never figure why it happens. It works for up to `1.99` but not for `2` limit. I think it encountered internal error and did not know how to recover from it.  If you change `StreamPlot` with `ContourPlot` it works with no problem.

Comment: ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lh2f8.png)